# Is there any advantage to appending to the end of a string over prepending to the beginning of one in python?

Tags: python, string, performance, memory

In *Elements of Programming Interviews in Python*, the authors claim that

> adding a digit to the beginning of a string is expensive, since all remaining digits have to be moved. A more time efficient approach is to add each computed digit to the end, and then reverse the computed sequence.

They then give the following solution to a problem:

```
def int_to_string(x: int) -> str:
  is_negative = False
  if x < 0:
    x, is_negative = -x, True
  s = []
  while True:
    s.append(chr(ord('0') + x % 10))
    x //= 10
    if x == 0:
      break
  return ('-' if is_negative else '') + ''.join(reversed(s))
```

I agree that adding to the end of a *list* is cheaper than adding to the beginning. That is what they're doing. I disagree with their statement about strings, since strings are immutable in Python.

Is there any truth to the statement "creating a new string by adding to the end of one string is more expensive than creating a new string adding to the beginning of one"?

Comment: CPython does happen to have a weird optimization that will sometimes mutate strings when you append to them, but it's highly unreliable, and you should still avoid appending to strings in a loop.

Comment: Its a misstatement. Given the code example, I'm sure the author meant the intermediate list.